# Laravel job runs multiple times when executing long task

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, ffmpeg-php, laravel-jobs

I'm currently trying to convert a video into multiple .ts segments (for HTTP video streaming). This is a long task so I'm doing this in a Laravel job.

The problem is that the job run multiple times after a few minutes and because of that, the video is processed multiple times. Here you can see my Job class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Media\MediaFile;
use FFMpeg\Filters\Video\ResizeFilter;
use FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use FFMpeg;

class ConvertVideoForStreaming implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public $mediaFile;
    public $deleteWhenMissingModels = true;
    public $timeout = 3600;
    public $retryAfter = 4000;
    public $tries = 3;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(MediaFile $mediaFile)
    {
        $this->mediaFile = $mediaFile;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->mediaFile->update([
            'status' => 'Processing',
            'status_message' => null,
        ]);


        $convertingId = Str::random(6);


        $lowBitrateFormat  = (new X264('aac', 'libx264'))
            ->setKiloBitrate(500)
            ->setAudioKiloBitrate(128);
        $midBitrateFormat  = (new X264('aac', 'libx264'))
            ->setKiloBitrate(1500)
            ->setAudioKiloBitrate(192);
        $highBitrateFormat = (new X264('aac', 'libx264'))
            ->setKiloBitrate(3000)
            ->setAudioKiloBitrate(256);

        \Log::info('Started a new converting process with convertingID: ' . $convertingId);

        FFMpeg::fromDisk('public')
            ->open($this->mediaFile->file)
            ->exportForHLS()
            ->setSegmentLength(4) // optional
            ->addFormat($lowBitrateFormat, function($media) {
                $media->addFilter(function ($filters) {
                    $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(640, 480), ResizeFilter::RESIZEMODE_INSET);
                });
            })
            ->addFormat($midBitrateFormat, function($media) {
                $media->addFilter(function ($filters) {
                    $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(1280, 720), ResizeFilter::RESIZEMODE_INSET);
                });
            })
            ->addFormat($highBitrateFormat, function($media) {
                $media->addFilter(function ($filters) {
                    $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(1920, 1080), ResizeFilter::RESIZEMODE_INSET);
                });
            })
            ->onProgress(function ($percentage) use($convertingId)  {
                \Log::info($this->mediaFile->name . " (ConvertingID: $convertingId) - $percentage % transcoded");
                \Redis::set('video-transcoded-' . $this->mediaFile->id, $percentage);
            })
            ->toDisk('public')
            ->save('livestream/' . Str::slug($this->mediaFile->name) . '/playlist.m3u8');

        $this->mediaFile->update([
            'status' => 'Active',
            'status_message' => null,
        ]);

    }


    public function failed(\Exception $exception)
    {
        $this->mediaFile->update([
            'status' => 'Failed',
            'status_message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        ]);
    }

}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Could you let us know how you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel offers a 'lock' feature for scheduled commands. See the 'Prevent Task Overlaps' in [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) documentation.

In case you'd like to have non-scheduled jobs being processed only once I'd advise you to look into the [Symfony Lock Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html). This component offers you to lock a certain task for a period of time or until it's unlocked. This way you can do something along the lines of:

1. At the start of your `handle()` method
   a. check if a lock already exists, otherwise skip this job
   b. If the lock does not exist, create it
2. Execute your long running task
3. At the end of your `handle()` logic release the lock